# Office.js Apps: Excel cannot find the home.html file

Tags: javascript, windows, ms-office, office-js

I'm trying to learn how to write Office.js apps. I did use the example given [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/mt616491.aspx).
Manifest file, QuarterlySalesReportManifest.xml, I did change the value of SourceLocation element to "\MY-PC\MySharedApp" which is the location of the "home.html". I also placed QuarterlySalesReportManifest.xml in another folder, "\MY-PC\MyManifest" and added this folder as a share location that contains the manifest as a trusted app catalog in Excel.

When I try to run the app from Excel it seem the QuarterlySalesReportManifest.xml is recognized but it searches for Home.js file without success and give an error message

```
Cannot find 'file://my-pc/MySharedApp/Home.html?_host_info=Exc...
Make sure the path or internet address is correct.
```

I do not know where am doing wrong because the path entered is as i got from Windows Explorer. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the add-in's manifest can be hosted on a file share (and thus served through the "file" protocol), the add-in itself has to be served through http/https. I'd recommend either hosting the file locally through IIS during development or using Visual Studio for developing your add-in.

Gabriel Royer - Developer on the Office Extensibility Team, MSFT

Comment: Thank you for your eye opener. I think the tutorial on this should also have at least a more detailed explanation about this because no where such kind of explanation could be found.

Comment: I'll let our documentation team know.