# OfficeJS FunctionFile resid on shared drive

Tags: javascript, html, xml, excel, office-js

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998519/office-js-apps-excel-cannot-find-the-home-html-file) might be the answer, but i'm looking for clarification.  I have an OfficeJS application tied to a shared network drive:

```
<!-- Icon -->
<IconUrl DefaultValue="\\Networked\Drive\icon.png" /> 

<!-- Location of Shared Folder + HTML to display in pane -->
<DefaultSettings>
  <SourceLocation DefaultValue="\\Networked\Drive\index.html" />
</DefaultSettings>
```

Here's the top of my `manifest.xml` hosted on `\\Networked\Drive\manifest.xml`.  Later i'm trying to make a button tied to a javascript function, and am refreshing my OfficeAddin shared folder page after every xml edit.  I get to this point:

```
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" 
                  xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
            <FunctionFile resid="PLP.FunctionFile.Url" />
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">

            </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <!-- Variable Names by ID -->
    <Resources>    
      <bt:Urls>
              <!-- But if I change this to DefaultValue="https://www.google.com", everything works -->
              <bt:Url id="PLP.FunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="\\Networked\Drive\functions.html" />
          </bt:Urls>
```

Before the refreshing pops up and says "no add-ins currently available".  Can you not link to local/networked files then like the hyperlink posted about it having to be http/https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SourceLocation and the FunctionFile URL must be https: URLs.

Comment: SourceLocation is working fine for me, it's ust when I try to make the FunctionFile local.  Thanks for the answer even though its not the one I wanted to hear. :(